# Inserting element in a doubly linked list

Tags: java, linked-list, doubly-linked-list

I'm trying to implement an `insertAfterNth` method that inserts an element after the nth(starting from 1, not 0) element on a doubly linked list. And, I'm stuck in setting the previous node to the node that I'm trying to insert. I need some help on figuring out the problem. Thanks.

```
public class DListNode {
    public DListNode next;
    public DListNode prev;
    public int item;

    ...
}

public void insertAfterNth(int n, int item) {

    if (n > length() || n < 1) {
      System.out.println("error: out of bounds");
      return;
    }
    else if (n == length()) {
      insertEnd(item);
    }
    DListNode walker = head;
    int i = 1;
    while (i != n) {
      i++;
      walker = walker.next;
    }
    DListNode node = new DListNode(item);
    node.next = walker.next;
    walker.next.prev = node; /* not sure if this line of code is right, regardless this method is giving me errors(I'm most certain that this line is causing the problem)*/
    walker.next = node;
    node.prev = walker;
    size++;
}
```

Comment: Can't see the problem, but why don't you try and set a `after` node to `walker.next` and work from there? The code would be much more simple. Also, rename `walker` to `before`.

Comment: In principle the code is ok. But you need to handle the special cases to insert at the front or at the end of the list separately.

Answer (score 0):

try using

- (walker.next).prev

I might be wrong.

Answer (score 0):

The code is mostly correct. You must add a method for inserting at the start of the list, but from your description/method name, it seems that you insert **after** a node so there may be no point in adding insertion at the start. You must check for the case when the head node is null. Another sugestion is to return a boolean value if the operation was successful. Another good return can be the newly inserted node or null if the operation failed. You may also throw an exception if you don't wish to return a value.

```
public class DoubleLinkedList {

private DListNode head;
private DListNode tail;
private int size;

private class DListNode {
    private DListNode next;
    private DListNode prev;
    private int item;

    private DListNode(final int item) {
        this.item = item;
    }
}

public void insertAfterNth(final int n, final int item) {
    if (size == 0) {
        System.out.println("error: list is empty");
    } else if ((n > size) || (n < 1)) {
        System.out.println("error: out of bounds");
        return;
    } else if (n == size) {
        insertEnd(item);
    } 
    DListNode walker = head;
    int i = 1;
    while (i < n) {
        i++;
        walker = walker.next;
    }
    DListNode node = new DListNode(item);
    node.next = walker.next;
    walker.next.prev = node;
    walker.next = node;
    node.prev = walker;
    size++;
}

private void insertEnd(int item) {
    size++;
    final DListNode newItem = new DListNode(item);
    if (head == null) {
        head = newItem;
        tail = newItem;
    } else {
        tail.next = newItem;
        newItem.prev = tail;
        tail = newItem;
    }
}

public void add(final int item) {
    insertEnd(item);
}

//the rest of operations you wish to implement
```

}